# How can I transfer data with multiple hosts through PSCP

Tags: remote

```
pscp -h host.txt terminal.sh /Desktop/terminal.sh
```

I tried this command to copy the file `terminal.sh` from my Desktop to my client Desktop using `pscp` but I got these errors:

```
[1] 22:34:05 [FAILURE] 10.20.10.214 Exited with error code 1
[2] 22:34:05 [FAILURE] 10.20.10.201 Exited with error code 1
```

How can I copy that file from my computer to multiple client computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command instead.

```
pscp -h host.txt -l <username> -Av terminal.sh /tmp/
```

I think you are getting the error because of permission issue.(Assuming that there is actually a directory under `/` named Desktop)

Or if you want to copy that file to home directory of a user, then you might need to cross check the destination path specified in your command.

Normally user home directories are under `/home/` directory. So if you haven't changed your client machine's home directory,you can try the following command to copy the file.

```
pscp -h host.txt -l <username> -Av terminal.sh /home/<username>/Desktop/
```

If the above given command doesn't solve your problem, you can generate error log using the following command. So that you can understand whether the issue is due to file permission or authentication failure, etc.

```
pscp -h host.txt -e error -Av terminal.sh /Desktop/terminal.sh
```

Comment: Thank you this command is working! how can i retrieve  files from my clients computers?

Comment: @TharmalingamMayuran I don't think there is such a option available. You need to run the command from the remote machine i think.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
pslurp -h hosts.txt /Desktop/terminal.sh
```

this command upload files on multiple servers. pslurp is part of pssh package.